# How to recalculate amperes to amperes/micron (transistor characterstics)

Tags: transistors, conversion, units

I measured the transfer characteristic of P-type FET (so I have drain current versus gate voltage.)

The authors usually present results in μA/μm (microampere/micron) versus V (volt.)

Because I have the drain current in μA, should I divide my results by the channel width to get μA/μm?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if that's the metric you want. Divide the drain current by the drain width. Keep in mind that the **width** of the drain (which is also the width of the gate and source) is usually the larger value...the gate **length** is the distance between the source and drain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in my case (https://postimg.cc/yWZrVgrG), should I divide by 2 μA? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: I have no idea what that image is supposed to be.

Comment: The sample is laying on the gold electrodes. The distance between them is 2 μm. The width of the sample is 500 nm. The gold electrodes are deposited on SiO2.

Comment: @Tester321:  The link goes what appear to be pictures of warts.

Comment: OK, if you can check this figure (https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0191/2296/files/gfet-example-graphene-channel-opt_large.jpg?v=1530236803). The distance between the drain and source is 2 μm. But the width is 500 nm. Should I divide by 2 μm?

Comment: A site with "shopify" in its URL? Not a chance. Include the information in your question, and make it clear where the source, drain, and gate structures are.

Comment: I've updated my figure (https://i.postimg.cc/htWB3wMK/Bez-tytu-u.png). I hope that now it is easy to understand.